# Conformal application $\mathbb C\to D_1(0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

denote $D_1(0)$ the unit disc. Show that there is no conformal application from $\mathbb C\longrightarrow D_1(0)$. I tried to do by contradiction, but I can't conclude. Is there an other way ?

Comment: This is Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a such application would exist, it would be bounded (indeed, $|f(z)|<1$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$) and thus by Liouville theorem it would be constant. This is a contradiction by the fact that a conformal application is bijective.